# Truffle migrate: Could Not Find .sol file from any sources

Tags: truffle-migration

I just started onto the blockchain journey a couple of hours back trying to create an elections program on the Ethereum blockchain. While trying to migrate the smart contracts using `truffle migrate`, I encountered a roadblock which says the following:

[image]

I'm stuck and need some help.
I have been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3681ZYbDSSk

Thanks!

Comment: what does your migrations file look like, or your contracts directory, oftentimes if you just proceed further along in the video that might be enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only to imagine the root cause of an error based on provided information.

Most probably you've updated migration script with proper path to solidity file, but put the file in a wrong place.

All contracts should be in `contracts` sub-directory of project root. In order to check structure you can run `truffle compile` and check result of completion (`build` directory).

Answer (score 1):

I was also following the same video and had this same issue. The thing that RESOLVED this issue for me was to "SAVE" the files in which I was working.

Answer (score 1):

All file contract(.sol) be in contract folder and you also have to create a migrationjs for same in migration folder and use sudo command if you face any permission issue.